# Problems with AngularJS and Select event ng-change not firing / ng-blur

Tags: angularjs, html

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and have been trying to develop an interactive form to experiment and learn.

The goal is to do the following:

1. Display a list of items from a list using AngularJS {{template}} [WORKING]
2. When that object is clicked, hide it, and show a drop-down selection. [WORKING]
3. After an item is selected OR focus is lost, hide the drop-down selector. [BROKEN]

As an example, it would display:

> My favorite fruit is: APPLE
>
> My favorite color is: BLUE

Then if you click APPLE it would hide the word "APPLE" and display a drop-down list with other options.

> My favorite fruit is: [select]
>
> [option]APPLE[/option]
>
> [option]ORANGE[/option]
>
> [/select]

I have this working with the code below, but I am running into issues hiding the select box under the following conditions:

1. Select box is created, but the user clicks away from it. Symptom: Select box stays and is never hidden again
2. Select box is created, same item as before is selected. Symptom: the ng-change event does not fire in this case so I cannot hide it.

I have tried several ways to fix this including trying ng-blur and to add some jQuery but was wondering if someone could tell me the correct way to accomplish this.

```
    function OutputController($scope) {

     $scope.query = {
         'Fav Fruit': {
             'options': [ 'Apples', 'Oranges','Banana']
         },
         'Select thickness of slice': {
             'default': 1,
             'options': [ '0.8mm / 0.031”', '1.6mm / 0.063”', '2.0mm / 0.079”']
         },
             'Surface Finish': {
             'options': ['Raw','Polish / Wax','Gold' ]
         }
     };

     $scope.updateOnBlur = function () {
         for (name in $scope.requirements) {
             $scope.query[name].showEdit = 0;
         }
     };
  };
```

```
Click on any of the items below:

<div ng-app>
    <div id="app_container" ng-controller="OutputController">
        <div ng-repeat="(name,entry) in query"><span ng-click="updateOnBlur(); entry.showEdit = true;">{{name}}: </span><span style="text-indent: 4px;" ng-show="!entry.showEdit" ng-click="updateOnBlur(); entry.showEdit = true;">{{entry.SelectedOption}}</span>
        <select class="requirements" ng-show="entry.showEdit" ng-blur="updateOnBlur()" ng-init="entry.SelectedOption = entry.options[entry.default || 0]" ng-change="updateOnBlur()" ng-model="entry.SelectedOption" ng-options="option for option in entry.options"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.requirements` not exist in your controller change it to `$scope.query` in your updateOnBlur  function;

change

```
$scope.updateOnBlur = function () {
         for (name in $scope.requirements) {
             $scope.query[name].showEdit = 0;
         }
     };
```

to

```
$scope.updateOnBlur = function () {

         for (name in $scope.query) {

             $scope.query[name].showEdit = 0;
         }
     };
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.query = {
    'Fav Fruit': {
      'options': ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Banana']
    },
    'Select thickness of slice': {
      'default': 1,
      'options': ['0.8mm / 0.031”', '1.6mm / 0.063”', '2.0mm / 0.079”']
    },
    'Surface Finish': {
      'options': ['Raw', 'Polish / Wax', 'Gold']
    }
  };

  $scope.updateOnBlur = function() {

    for (name in $scope.query) {

      $scope.query[name].showEdit = 0;
    }
  };


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(name,entry) in query"><span ng-click="updateOnBlur(); entry.showEdit = true;">{{name}}: </span><span style="text-indent: 4px;" ng-show="!entry.showEdit" ng-click="updateOnBlur(); entry.showEdit = true;">{{entry.SelectedOption}}</span>
      <select ng-show="entry.showEdit" class="requirements" ng-blur="updateOnBlur()" ng-init="entry.SelectedOption = entry.options[entry.default || 0]" ng-change="updateOnBlur()" ng-model="entry.SelectedOption" ng-options="option for option in entry.options"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```